# jquery ajax binding not getting available on asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jquery, viewstate

I am binding a country state city dropdown on an asp.net page using jquery ajax.
All goes well until the page is posted back to the server. The values that user selected for country state and city doesn't gets available to submit function.

Reason for this seems to be dropdown items getting binded from ajax are not written to viewstate and hence on submit no values is found.

What can be the workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only that, with the ViewState validation turned on, you should also get a security exception - since the value the page POSTs with is not at the list of available values.

Web Forms engine is a paranoiac when it comes to request validation.

The usual solution is to:
1) disable event validation for the page
2) do not rely on `SelectedItem` of the combo (as the value the browser submits is not on the list) but rather read it from a lower level `this.Request.Form["dropdownID"]`.

Comment: exactly, I have to turned off the eventPageValidation.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution hidden box saves selected value. if page postback, if the hidden box value is not empty, use the value read from hidden box for server side processing. "ViewState is not responsible for form field values. So use hidden field to save the value."

Check it yourself.

```
C#
   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string id = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            id = this.Label1.ClientID;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string testvalue = this.Label1.Value; 
        }
    }
//break down at button1_click


 <asp:HiddenField ID="Label1" runat="server" Value="" /> 


javascript 



     $(document).ready(function () {


                $("#"+'<%=id%>').val("test");

            });
```

So all you need to do is add a event listener to dropdownbox when item is selected update the value for hidden field, then when server side click event happens, use the value from hidden field, Personally, I don't like to turn off viewstate validation.